# Transfer files between two server in SpringMVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm a newbie in SpringMVC, today i'm have a problem about transfer files between two servers.
I want to send a folder contains muti-file from server A to Server B, but I don't know how to 
develop it, please anybody give me some suggests or tutorials relevant it!